# What is the right way to check for a null string in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I was using this in my iPhone app

```
if (title == nil) {
    // do something
}
```

but it throws some exception, and the console shows that the title is "(null)".

So I'm using this now:

```
if (title == nil || [title isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    //do something
}
```

What is the difference, and what is the best way to determine whether a string is null?

Comment: Solution : http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/09/better-way-to-check-empty-string.html

Answer (score 408, accepted):

As others have pointed out, there are many kinds of "null" under Cocoa/Objective C.  But one further thing to note is that [title isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] is pointlessly complex since [NSNull null] is documented to be a singleton so you can just check for pointer equality. See [Topics for Cocoa: Using Null](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html).

So a good test might be:

```
if (title == (id)[NSNull null] || title.length == 0 ) title = @"Something";
```

Note how you can use the fact that even if title is nil, title.length will return 0/nil/false, ie 0 in this case, so you do not have to special case it.  This is something that people who are new to Objective C have trouble getting used to, especially coming form other languages where messages/method calls to nil crash.

Comment: Thanks! However I asked this question in the first place because I was getting exception because the "title" null.

Comment: What type is title supposed to be? If it's an NSString, for instance, I receive the following warning: 

comparison of distinct Objective-C types 'struct NSNull *' and 'struct NSString *' lacks a cast

Is there any way of removing this (I dunno if things have changed since this question was asked)?

Comment: Serves me right for posting code without compiling it ;-).  title is presumably an NSString, but regardless of title's type, just cast null to the generic id type: (id)[NSNull null].

Comment: @PeterNLewis Hi, I tested a case by setting a string to nil and see if it passes this statement: if(string == (id)[NSNull null]). But it never passed. Can you cite a sample where string will be equal to [NSNull null]. ?

Comment: @JLT nil and [NSNull null] will never be the same.  [NSNull null] is a singleton object that can be used as a stand in for nil when nil cannot be used (eg in an NSArray or NSDictionary value). So a use case might be where you had an NSArray of optional strings, some of which might be null, and you use [NSNull null] in the array for the null cases.  In practice, the test is rarely needed, only when you (or a library you use!) actively use [NSNull null] as a placeholder.

Comment: The main difference is that `nil` is, well, a **pointer to nothing** (effectively being a "null pointer"), that's represented by the memory address `0x0` and it comes from `NULL` in C. `[NSNull null]`, at the other side, is an **object** that is considered a null value-representation by convention (it's different than `0x0` memory address, but as a singleton, it will take only one fixed memory address at runtime). As collections like `NSArray *` and `NSDictionary *`, amongst others, can't take null pointers, they will accept `[NSNull null]` without problems, since it is an instantiated object.

Comment: Coming here from Flutter, and looking for the reason why a `Map` item's value - which is `null` in Dart - doesn't correspond to `nil` or `NULL` in Objective C. The reason was that it is actually `NUNull null`, not the `NULL` null. Thank You @PeterNLewis !

Answer (score 25):

it is just as simple as

```
if([object length] >0)
{
  // do something
}
```

remember that in objective C if object is null it returns 0 as the value.

This will get you both a null string and a 0 length string.

Comment: This won't work if object is NSNull, still need to explicitly check that first.

Comment: you could also make a category for NSNull to make it return 0 to the length message :)

Comment: Yup, this'll crash if the object is NSNull.

Comment: This will crash if object is equal to NSNull

Comment: In addition to the NSNull unrecognized selector issue, this won't differentiate between a NSString pointer that is nil, or a NSString that is actually there but is essentially an empty string. (For example as a literal `object = @"";` or `object = nil;`)

Comment: What if the string is just empty, but not nil?

Answer (score 6):

Refer to the following related articles on this site:

- [Is if (variable) the same as if (variable != nil) in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535120/is-if-variable-the-same-as-if-variable-nil-in-objective-c)
  h

I think your error is related to something else as you shouldn't need to do the extra checking.

Also see this related question: [Proper checking of nil sqlite text column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598396/proper-checking-of-nil-sqlite-text-column)

Comment: Annoyingly I don't have enough "points" to add a second hyperlink (even to something on this site)
see also:  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598396/proper-checking-of-nil-sqlite-text-column

Comment: ...allow me. Although you should be able to edit your own posts from rep 0.

Comment: Thanks - that was very kind. When I wrote my initial post it said something like new users can only add 1 hyperlink (which seems a bit harsh - especially for cross links in this site).

Answer (score 6):

I have found that in order to really do it right you end up having to do something similar to

```
if ( ( ![myString isEqual:[NSNull null]] ) && ( [myString length] != 0 ) ) {
}
```

Otherwise you get weird situations where control will still bypass your check. I haven't come across one that makes it past the `isEqual` and length checks.

Answer (score 5):

Whats with all these "works for me answers" ? We're all coding in the same language and the rules are

1. Ensure the reference isn't **nil**
2. Check and make sure the length of the string isn't 0

That is what will work for all. If a given solution only "works for you", its only because your application flow won't allow for a scenario where the reference may be null or the string length to be 0. The proper way to do this is the method that will handle what you want in all cases.

Comment: If the reference is *`nil`* (note: not "null"), then sending a message, like `length`, will produce 0 (or the appropriate 0-value for the method's return type). _That's_ the rule of the language. There's no need to check for `nil` separately in this case.

Comment: I said null simply because of C++ habits, and if your code is calling methods on nil objects, chances are your code is broken. You'll find that calling methods on NULL/NIL (same concept) is generally a bad idea in any language. Just because obj-c lets you do something like that doesn't mean you should just be passing around nil objects and trying to use them without caring.

Comment: Sending length to nil does produce 0 - BUT sending length to NSNull produces an exception.

Comment: @nenchev Nobody says anything about just passing around nil objects, but checking for nil, then calling a method and using its return value is IMO worse than using a language feature like it's meant to be used and checking validity of the method's return value afterwards.

Comment: @Kevin I'm not sure how its worse really, just because its a language feature doesn't mean its great. Not checking if its null could open up a code path that could lead to a harder to trace runtime error. Its usually best to verify that your inputs are as you expect, and react accordingly if they are not. I don't personally like the "feature" of not getting run-time exceptions when trying to send a message to a nil object, as it often makes it easier to miss some runtime bugs.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to test against all nil/empty objects (like empty strings or empty arrays/sets) you can use the following:

```
static inline BOOL IsEmpty(id object) {
    return object == nil
        || ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(length)]
        && [(NSData *) object length] == 0)
        || ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(count)]
        && [(NSArray *) object count] == 0);
}
```

Comment: This does not actually check for object == [NSNull null] which would probably make sense.

Answer (score 4):

There are two situations:

It is possible that an object is `[NSNull null]`, or it is impossible.
 Your application usually shouldn't use `[NSNull null];` you only use it if you want to put a "*null*" object into an array, or use it as a dictionary value. And then you should know which arrays or dictionaries might contain null values, and which might not.
 If you think that an array never contains `[NSNull null]` values, then don't check for it. If there is an `[NSNull null]`, you might get an exception but that is fine: Objective-C exceptions indicate programming errors. And you have a programming error that needs fixing by changing some code.

If an object *could* be `[NSNull null]`, then you check for this quite simply by testing
 `(object == [NSNull null])`. Calling `isEqual` or checking the class of the object is nonsense. There is only one `[NSNull null]` object, and the plain old C operator checks for it just fine in the most straightforward and most efficient way.

If you check an `NSString` object that cannot be `[NSNull null]` (because you know it cannot be `[NSNull null]` or because you just checked that it is different from `[NSNull null]`, then you need to ask yourself how you want to treat an empty string, that is one with length 0. If you treat it is a `null` string like `nil`, then test `(object.length == 0)`. object.length will return 0 if `object == nil`, so this test covers nil objects and strings with length 0. If you treat a string of length 0 different from a nil string, just check if `object == nil`.

Finally, if you want to add a string to an array or a dictionary, and the string could be nil, you have the choice of not adding it, replacing it with `@""`, or replacing it with `[NSNull null]`. Replacing it with `@""` means you lose the ability to distinguish between "no string" and "string of length 0". Replacing it with `[NSNull null]` means you have to write code when you access the array or dictionary that checks for `[NSNull null]` objects.

Comment: Very long, but this is good. NSNull should ONLY APPEAR IN SINGLETONS! This whole question makes no sense, tells me the coder wasn't doing something correct, and many more in the future also, didn't read the manual/good code practice

Answer (score 3):

You just check for nil

```
if(data[@"Bonds"]==nil){
  NSLog(@"it is nil");
}
```

or

```
if ([data[@"Bonds"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    NSLog(@"it is null");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## MACRO Solution (2020)

Here is the macro that I use for safe string instead of getting "**(null)**" string on a *[UILabel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel)* for example:

```
#define SafeString(STRING) ([STRING length] == 0 ? @"" : STRING)
```

let say you have an member class and name property, and name is nil:

```
NSLog(@"%@", member.name); // prints (null) on UILabel
```

with macro:

```
NSLog(@"%@", SafeString(member.name)); // prints empty string on UILabel
```

nice and clean

## Extension Solution (2020)

If you prefer checking nil Null and empty string in your project you can use my extension line below:

**NSString+Extension.h**

```
///
/// Checks if giving String is an empty string or a nil object or a Null.
/// @param string string value to check.
///
+ (BOOL)isNullOrEmpty:(NSString*)string;
```

**NSString+Extension.m**

```
+ (BOOL)isNullOrEmpty:(NSString*)string {
    if (string) { // is not Nil
        NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:string];
        BOOL isEmpty = (range.length <= 0 || [string isEqualToString:@" "]);
        BOOL isNull = string == (id)[NSNull null];

        return (isNull || isEmpty);
    }

    return YES;
}
```

#### Example Usage

```
if (![NSString isNullOrEmpty:someTitle]) {
    // You can safely use on a Label or even add in an Array for example. Remember: Arrays don't like the nil values!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(textfield.text.length == 0){
   //do your desired work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for check null

```
 if (text == nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface NSString (StringFunctions)
- (BOOL) hasCharacters;
@end

@implementation NSString (StringFunctions)
- (BOOL) hasCharacters {
    if(self == (id)[NSNull null]) {
        return NO;
    }else {
        if([self length] == 0) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
@end

NSString *strOne = nil;
if([strOne hasCharacters]) {
    NSLog(@"%@",strOne);
}else {
    NSLog(@"String is Empty");
}
```

This would work with the following cases, `NSString *strOne = @""` OR `NSString *strOne = @"StackOverflow"` OR `NSString *strOne = [NSNull null]` OR `NSString *strOne`.

Answer (score 0):

If that kind of thing does not already exist, you can make an NSString category:

```
@interface NSString (TrucBiduleChoseAdditions)

- (BOOL)isEmpty;

@end

@implementation NSString (TrucBiduleChoseAdditions)

- (BOOL)isEmpty {
    return self == nil || [@"" isEqualToString:self];
}

@end
```

Comment: That's probably overkill and I don't think it'll solve this problem.

Comment: The self == nil is pointless - if self was nil, Objective C would not have called you in the first place.  [(NSString*)nil isEmpty] would simply return 0/nil/false without ever calling your code.

Comment: Actually, further to that, [(NSString*)nil isEmpty] will return false.  When writing such Objective C methods, it is better to define them so that nil's 0/nil/false makes sense, so writing the method as hasCharacters would be better.  Note that length already works for this, as you can use if ( s.length ) anywhere you would want to use if ( !s.isEmpty ) and s.length will correctly return 0 for the s == nil case.

Comment: This is a serious crash. You implemented "isEmpty" for NSString, but if it is actually NSNull, then isEmpty will be sent to NSNull, and crash because it does not respond to that message!

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is `if ( !myobject  )`

Comment: That doesn't work for null objects, only nil objects. For example...

`NSArray *testarray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNull null],@"", nil];
NSString *string = [testarray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"null string value: %@",string);
if (!string) {
    NSLog(@"string evaluates to null");
}
if (string && (string==(id)[NSNull null])) {
    NSLog(@"string does not evaluate to null");
}`

Comment: Err.. sorry about the formatting, but the code will compile :)

Answer (score 0):

Complete checking of a string for null conditions can be a s follows :<\br>

```
    if(mystring)
     {
       if([mystring isEqualToString:@""])
        {
          mystring=@"some string";
        }
     }    
    else
     {
        //statements
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I only check null string with

> if ([myString isEqual:[NSNull null]])

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([linkedStr isEqual:(id)[NSNull null]])
                {
                    _linkedinLbl.text=@"No";
                }else{
                    _linkedinLbl.text=@"Yes";
                }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([strpass isEqual:[NSNull null]] || strpass==nil || [strpass isEqualToString:@"<null>"] || [strpass isEqualToString:@"(null)"] || strpass.length==0 || [strpass isEqualToString:@""])
{
    //string is blank  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For string:

```
+ (BOOL) checkStringIsNotEmpty:(NSString*)string {
if (string == nil || string.length == 0) return NO;
return YES;
```

}

Refer the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For string:

```
+ (BOOL) checkStringIsNotEmpty:(NSString*)string {
if (string == nil || string.length == 0) return NO;
return YES;}
```