# not able to compare (null)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the right way to check for a null string in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968792/what-is-the-right-way-to-check-for-a-null-string-in-objective-c)

if my url is null i should assign the url variable with empty..i ve tried but still not getting entered in my IF statement.i even tried this `if([url isEqualToString:@""])`
but its in vain
below is the code

```
-(void)newView:(NSString *)title Description:(NSString *)desc URL:(NSString *)url{
self.tblTwitter.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
self.tblFacebook.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

if (![url isEqualToString:@""])
{
    //
    NSLog(@"the perfect Value:%@",url);
 //   url=@"boom";
}
webView =[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 25, 190, 190)];
webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
webView.delegate=self;
webView.opaque = NO;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try that :

```
if (url == nil)
```

nil is the Objective-C for NULL, and nil doesn't means empty.

This answer might be what you're looking for : [What is the right way to check for a null string in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968792/what-is-the-right-way-to-check-for-a-null-string-in-objective-c)