# NSView Drag Operation Error

Tags: macos, cocoa, encoding, drag-and-drop, nsview

I'm coding in Cocoa, on OS X.

I'm trying to receive a file that is dragged and dropped onto my NSView subclass - which I can do; and **get its contents and filename and display them** - which I can do for any type of file **first time**, but **on the second time, when I try and drag another file on, I can only set the title `setTitle:`, but not the main body text `setText:`**

**The errors I am getting are:**

> Canceling drag because exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' (reason 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString != nil') was raised during a dragging session

and

> Assertion failure in -[NSTextFieldCell _objectValue:forString:errorDescription:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1187/AppKit.subproj/NSCell.m:1532

**My code (sorry, it's quite long!):**

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
NSPasteboard *pboard;
NSDragOperation sourceDragMask;

sourceDragMask = [sender draggingSourceOperationMask];
pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];

if ([[pboard types] containsObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]) {

    NSURL *file = [NSURL URLFromPasteboard:pboard];
    //NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:file];

    NSError *error;
    NSStringEncoding encoding;
    NSString *contentString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);

    NSString *last = [[file path] lastPathComponent];
    NSArray *parts = [last componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSString *filename = [parts objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileType = [parts objectAtIndex:1];

    NSLog(@"FILETYPE: %@", fileType);

    if ([fileType isEqualToString:@"txt"] || [fileType isEqualToString:@"md"]) {
        [self setTitle:filename];

        if (self.textViewString == (id)[NSNull null] || self.textViewString.length == 0) {
            [self setText:contentString];
        } else {
            BOOL whatToDo = (NSRunCriticalAlertPanel(@"What do you want to do?", nil, @"Append", @"Replace", nil) == NSAlertDefaultReturn);

            if (whatToDo) {
                //Append
                [self setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",self.textViewString,contentString]];
            } else {
                //Replace
                [self setText:contentString];
            }
        }
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
} else if ([[pboard types] containsObject:NSPasteboardTypeString]) {
    NSString *draggedString = [pboard stringForType:NSPasteboardTypeString];

    if (self.textViewString == (id)[NSNull null] || self.textViewString.length == 0) {
        [self setText:draggedString];
    } else {
        [self setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",self.textViewString,draggedString]];
    }
    return YES;
}
else {
    return NO;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of thanks for the many tips and pieces of advice from [this answer by Conrad Shultz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11704702/447697)! I've followed the advice and tips there.

However, my problem turned out to be very, very basic. It lied in the line `BOOL whatToDo = (NSRunCriticalAlertPanel(@"What do you want to do?", nil, @"Append", @"Replace", nil) == NSAlertDefaultReturn);`

It turns out a string **must** be passed to the second parameter, but I was passing `nil`. Fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like Cocoa is canceling the drag when any exception is raised, and an exception is getting raised when something internally is expecting a string and is getting a `nil` value instead.

It's just a guess without having more information, but I would predict that `stringWithFormat:` is raising the exception, as it looks like the only really potentially fragile bit of what you have written.

You are doing a couple ill-advised things.  First, you are assuming that `-initWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:` is succeeding.  You should not do this.  Instead, you need to pass an `NSError **` that can be filled in on error, test whether `contentString` is nil, and, if so, check the `error` accordingly.  I have a feeling that you will find you are getting `nil`, and the `error` will explain why.

Possibly unrelated, but your `if (whatToDo)` is not doing what you probably think it is.  Since `whatToDo` is a pointer to an autoreleased `NSNumber` instance your conditional will *always* evaluate to true, since the *pointer* is non-zero.  What you likely meant to do was something like the following:

```
 BOOL whatToDo = (NSRunCriticalAlertPanel(@"What do you want to do?", nil, @"Append", @"Replace", nil) == NSAlertDefaultReturn);

    if (whatToDo) {
        //Append
        [self setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",self.textViewString,contentString]];
    } else {
        //Replace

        [self setText:contentString];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that whatToDo segment is exactly what I meant, I didn't realise. I passed in an NSError and NSLogged it, but it came out as "(null)" so nothing wrong there I think. The behaviour I'm getting now is that any file is now read and displayed, but if I try again with any file it fails and NSLogs "Assertion failure in -[NSTextFieldCell _objectValue:forString:errorDescription:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1187/AppKit.subproj/NSCell.m:1532"

Comment: Can you post your updated code, including the `NSError` changes and the fix to `whatToDo`? Want to make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: What is `self.textViewString == (id)[NSNull null]` trying to do?  Did you mean `self.textViewString == nil`?

Comment: Trying to check whether the string is empty or null, I picked it up in [this Stack overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/974185/447697).

Comment: Not appropriate for this situation.  In Objective-C, `nil` and `NSNull` are quite different.  The former is basically a zero-value pointer, the latter an actual object understood to mean "empty", most commonly used in collections (e.g. `NSSet`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, etc.).

Comment: I've added more detail to the first paragraph of my original question.