# how to check if array is null or empty in ios sdk?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I want to check if my Bond is empty or null and NULL value.

```
{
Bonds =(
      {
        DOB = "12/09/1988";
        about = "";
      }
      );
User =     {
    city = CA;
    email = "karmhadadmtl@gmail.com";
};
success = True;
}
```

Second time this type get data how to check Bond key

```
{
Bonds = Null;
User =     {
    city = CA;
    email = "developer.i12@gmail.com";
};
success = True;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the right way to check for a null string in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968792/what-is-the-right-way-to-check-for-a-null-string-in-objective-c)

Comment: Apparently `nil` and `NULL` are two different kind of beasts...

Comment: Please state in which environment you are running in.

Comment: By the way: you confused "array" with "dictionary"

Comment: Please sir see my question

Answer (score 7):

You just check for `nil`

```
if(data[@"Bonds"]==nil){
  NSLog(@"it is nil");
}
```

or

```
if ([data[@"Bonds"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    NSLog(@"it is null");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if ([data[@"Bonds"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || data[@"Bonds"] == nil || [data[@"Bonds"] isEqualToString:@""]) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

[NSNull null] always returns a same object so this should work fine.

```
if (dictionary[@"Bonds"] != [NSNull null]) {
    // requried data is present, now check if it is nil or empty.
}
```

Comment: I think the solution is provided in the wrong implementation language. Null is not the same as NSNUll.

Comment: Perfect answer and the recommended way to check for NSNull objects.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson: It should be obvious that the output that you saw comes from an NSLog statement, and that's how NSLog logs NSNull objects. Your comment is totally wrong.

Comment: Hmmm... looking at the question there is nothing that indicates that this is an output from NSLog. It is clearly JSON output. However looking at the tags I would have noticed that this is Objective-C. So my bad.

Answer (score 2):

check: `if (![dataArray isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])` &&

check if it having elements `[dataArray firstObject]` - to check array having one or more elements.

Answer (score 1):

The best possible way should be:

```
if (!data[@"Bonds"] || ![data[@"Bonds"] count]){
    NSLog(@"Data Found");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Data Not Found");
}
```