# App crashing when i get array value as <null>

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app is Crashing when I get something like  value in array which comes in response.

Even after this check,

```
if(![[_stageDateArray  objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]&& ((![[_stageDateArray objectAtIndex:i]isEqualToString:@""]))){    
    NSDate * date=[self getDateFromString:strdate];          
    NSString *datestring=[self getStringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"");

}
```

Comment: Did you forget to check `_stageDateArray != nil`? What is `strdate` in your question?

Comment: check like `[[_stageDateArray objectAtIndex:i] length] != 0`

Comment: see this for e.g : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968792/what-is-the-right-way-to-check-for-a-null-string-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Same error i was receiving. This arrises due to -

```
[[_stageDateArray objectAtIndex:i]isEqualToString:@""]
```

Well the code check both condition - Null & Equal to string. **Try removing the isEqualToString:** condition in the if - statement

Answer (score 0):

Try with following condition,

```
if(_stageDateArray != nil && i < [_stageDateArray count] && [[_stageDateArray objectAtIndex:i] length] >= 1)
```