# how to remove the null value from NSMutablearray in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

As I am consuming the json web service and storing the value in NSMutablearray but I am getting the Null response.Now I want to remove that null value and replace it as empty.can anyone help me to solve this error.

```
(
        {
        Aadhar =1123323244;
        AddressProofCopy = "<null>";
        Advertisement = "<null>";
        AgreementCopy = "<null>";
        ApCity = ggg;
        ApDistrict = g;
        ApDoorNo = g;
        ApFGFirstName = v;
        ApFGSurName = g;
        ApGender = F;
        ApPIN = 12323;
        ApStreet = h;
        AppStatus = "<null>";
        ApplRefStageStatus = N;
        ApplicantFirstName = g;
        ApplicantPhoto = "<null>";
        ApplicantSurName = g;
        ApplicationDate = "2018-09-06T00:00:00.000Z";
        ApplicationType = New;
        BuldingType = "<null>";
        District = 132424;
        DistrictId = 11;
        DocVerifiedBy = "<null>";
        DocVerifiedDate = "<null>";
        DocVerifiedMessage = "<null>";
        DocVerifiedStatus = "<null>";
    }
)
```

Comment: Please share what your model looks like. Is it an array of dictionaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please verify this link.. https://github.com/bismasaeed00/NullReplacer its working fine for me.

try this..

```
#import "NSArray+NullReplacement.h"
#import "NSDictionary+NullReplacement.h"
```

After that pass your dictionary/array JSON response based on that use the below line,

```
NSArray *newvalue = [yourarrayresponse arrayByReplacingNullsWithBlanks];
```

or

```
NSDictionary *newvalue = [yourdictionary dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithBlanks];
```

If you get any error just add

```
#import "NSArray+NullReplacement.h"
```

in NSDictionary+NullReplacement class and

```
#import "NSDictionary+NullReplacement.h"
```

in NSDictionary+NullReplacement class file.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(NSDictionary *dic in array)
{
for (NSString *key in dictionar.allKeys)
{
    if ([[dictionary objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    {
        [dictionary setObject:@"" forKey:key];
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not null value but a string with value/characters `"<null>"`.

Here is full sample working code. You can use this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        @"1123323244",@"Aadhar",
                                        @"<null>",@"AddressProofCopy",
                                        nil];
    NSArray * array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mutableDict];

    for(NSDictionary *dic in array)
        {
            for (NSString *key in dic.allKeys)
            {
                if ([[dic valueForKey:key] isEqualToString:@"<null>"])
                {
                    [mutableDict setObject:@"" forKey:key];
                }

            }
        }

    NSLog(@"Updated dict - %@", mutableDict);
}

@end
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes i need to remove that values and replace as empty

Comment: how will you handle if another type of null for e.g `(null)`

Comment: @user19 - see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968792/what-is-the-right-way-to-check-for-a-null-string-in-objective-c